# Initializing Fuzzy C means clustering

Tags: clustering, matlab, fuzzy

I have been performing fuzzy c means clustering using Matlab toolbox for my clustering problem. Unfortunately it leads to unstable performance since the selection of parameter membership (Uij) is chosen randomly and the initial centres are derived from Uij. Is there any initial algorithm which can be performed for fuzzy c means algorithm? Thanks

Comment: If you get substantially different clusterings w/ different initial centers, that is something to pay close attention to, not something to wave away & ignore w/ some fancy code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. So from your statement I can conclude that random initial centers is essential for clustering process since it is a proof that our algorithm is converging or not. Is that right? and also how can we know that the algorithm works or not? I am new at this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment by @gung:

If you get very different results every time (not just a permutation of the clusters!) then this indicates the algorithm did not work. It did *not* converge to a solution that is clearly superior to the others.

You will need to carefully study your result and check if you can preprocess your data better, for example. (In fact, you should even do this if it had converged reliably...)

Comment: hi, in which condition can we say that our algorithm converges to a solution? Can we see it from the objective function of fcm?

Comment: The objective function value is very much data set dependent. You cannot compare it or tell if the value is good. You need to study (!) the actual clutering result.